# GWTP: Correct information flow for popup presenter

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

i had this task: I have Presenter/View Couple (lets call it ItemListPresenter) showing a Celltable. Now i wanted to edit an item by double-clicking it (or pressing a button, whatever). Then a popup dialog should appear (Lets call it PopupWidget), letting me edit my item properties. 
i found a solution how to do it, but i am not sure it is the "right" way. Since i am trying to learn the philosophy behind GWT/GWTP, i would appreciate if you could give me hints what i did right and what i did wrong:

In the onbind method of ItemListPresenter, i wire the CellTable with a DoubleClick handler:

```
getView().getCellTable().setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
getView().getCellTable().addDomHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {           
    @Override           
    public void onDoubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event) {
        DeviceDto selectedDeviceDto = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        //TODO: Figure out how to best handle editing of DeviceDto
        if (selectedDeviceDto != null) {
            devicesDialog.setCurrentDeviceDTO(selectedDeviceDto);
            addToPopupSlot(devicesDialog);
        }
} }, DoubleClickEvent.getType());
```

What does not feel right is setting the object i want to edit (selectedDeviceDto) in the Dialog Presenter Widget. Is this the "right" way?

My popup presenter which is defined as

```
public class DeviceEditDialogPresenterWidget extends PresenterWidget<DeviceEditDialogPresenterWidget.MyView> implements
            DeviceEditDialogUiHandlers {
```

is still ugly, since i just set every property into a text box and after editing, i recollect the properties and rebuild the object. This is messy and i guess i should GWT Editors for that. However, when i click the "Save" Button in the dialog, an UiHandler is triggered:

```
@UiHandler("okButton")
void okButtonClicked(ClickEvent event) {
    DeviceDto dev = new DeviceDto(idBox.getText(), deviceIdBox.getText(),    typeBox.getText(), firmwareVersionBox.getText(), userBox.getText(), statusBox.getText());
    getUiHandlers().updateDevice(dev);
    hide();
}
```

This triggers my DeviceEditDialogPresenterWidget, which itself fires and event:

```
@Override
public void updateDevice(DeviceDto device) {
    eventBus.fireEvent(new DeviceUpdatedEvent(device));
}
```

This event is caught by a handler in the "mother" presenter with the CellTable, which is wired in the onBind method again:

```
addRegisteredHandler(DeviceUpdatedEvent.TYPE, new DeviceUpdatedEvent.DeviceUpdatedHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDeviceUpdatedEvent(DeviceUpdatedEvent event) {
        updateDevice(event.getDevice());
    }
});
```

I would really like to avoid going down a road of messy mistakes, so any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PresenterWidgets` are usually designed to have a `setter` which is used to set a `Model` or `DTO` that the `PresenterWidget` works on (the same way you did it).

Alternatively you can avoid a `PresenterWidget` and use an `Editor` (extends Composite) that you manually add to a `PopupPanel` or `DialogBox` in your `ListItemEditor`.

This way you avoid the complexity of a `PresenterWidget`. But you have to handle the clicks (i.e. save button) from the `ListItemPresenter`. I would always try to start small (use a composite) and if you realize that you might need the functionality also in other places, create a `PresenterWidget`.

Also you don't need the `updateDevice` method because you pass a reference to your `DTO`. You only need to fresh the `CellTable`.
But apart from that your approach looks fine.

Comment: Is the approach i try in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555556/gwts-editor-framework-and-gwtp valid at all or should i reconsider and use a DialogBox and an Editor? I wanted to use the PresenterWidget to try to do it the GWTP way.