# GWT's Editor Framework and GWTP

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694589/how-to-use-gwts-editor-framework-with-gwt-platform), i try to integrate the GWT editors into a popup presenter widget. What is the right way to do that?

My view looks like this:

```
public class DeviceEditorDialogView extends
        PopupViewWithUiHandlers<DeviceEditorDialogUiHandlers> implements
        DeviceEditorDialogPresenterWidget.MyView {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<PopupPanel, DeviceEditorDialogView> {
    }
    public interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<DeviceDto, DeviceEditorDialogView> {
    }

    @Inject
    DeviceEditorDialogView(Binder uiBinder, EventBus eventBus) {
        super(eventBus);

        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }


    @Override
    public SimpleBeanEditorDriver<DeviceDto, ?> createEditorDriver() {
        Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
        driver.initialize(this);
        return driver;
    }

}
```

and my presenter looks like this:

```
public class DeviceEditorDialogPresenterWidget extends PresenterWidget<DeviceEditorDialogPresenterWidget.MyView> implements
            DeviceEditorDialogUiHandlers {

    @Inject
    DeviceEditorDialogPresenterWidget(EventBus eventBus,
                               MyView view) {
        super(eventBus, view);
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }
    /**
     * {@link LocalDialogPresenterWidget}'s PopupView.
     */
    public interface MyView extends PopupView, DevicesEditView<DeviceDto>, HasUiHandlers<DeviceEditorDialogUiHandlers> {

    }

    private DeviceDto currentDeviceDTO = null;

    private SimpleBeanEditorDriver<DeviceDto, ?> driver;

    public DeviceDto getCurrentDeviceDTO() {
        return currentDeviceDTO;
    }

    public void setCurrentDeviceDTO(DeviceDto currentDeviceDTO) {
        this.currentDeviceDTO = currentDeviceDTO;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();

        driver = getView().createEditorDriver();
    }
    //UiHandler Method: Person person = driver.flush();

}
```

Is this the right approach? What is missing? Currently nothing happens when i try to use it like this:

```
@Override
public void showDeviceDialog() {
    deviceEditorDialog.setCurrentDeviceDTO(new DeviceDto());
    addToPopupSlot(deviceEditorDialog);

}
```

showDeviceDialog is in the parent presenter and called when clicking a button in that parent Presenter, that instantiates the dialog with private final DeviceEditorDialogPresenterWidget deviceEditorDialog;

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the `GinInjector` error ?

Comment: I am sorry, i did a newbie mistake and forgot to bind the view and presenter in the ApplicationModule. I rephrased my question above, since i do not know if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few key points that are missing from your code above:

- Your `DeviceEditorDialogView` should implement `Editor<DeviceDto>`. This is required in order for the fields of `DeviceEditorDialogView` to be populated with data from you POJO.
- Your `DeviceEditorDialogView` should have child editors that are mapped to fields in your POJO. For example, given the field `deviceDto.modelName` (type `String`), you could have a GWT `Label` named `modelName` in your `DeviceEditorDialogView`. This `Label` implements `Editor<String>` and will be populated with the `modelName` from your `DeviceDto` when you call `driver.edit(deviceDto)`
- You should call `driver.initialize(this)` only once, in `DeviceEditorDialogView`'s constructor

You should override `onReveal()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();

    driver.edit(currentDeviceDTO); // this will populate your view with the data from your POJO
}
```

This method will be called when the popup is displayed, just after your `DeviceEditorDialogPresenterWidget` has been `addToPopupSlot`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! If i move the functionality of createEditorDriver() to the constructor, how should it look then? It must be implemented.

Comment: I just got it running :) My rep is too low, else i would vote you up. Thank you for the well structured answer.